# What is the 'input power lead'?

Tags: word-meaning

> He connects the LED driver to **the input power lead**.

It's about making LED light. I searched google about that part
but nothing found..
Is it powersupply or input jack?

Comment: See [*lead*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lead): "19. *countable noun* - A lead in a piece of equipment is a piece of wire covered in plastic which supplies electricity to the equipment or carries it from one part of the equipment to another."

Answer (score 1):

The word 'lead' in the context of electricity means an insulated wire. The 'input power lead' is the wire that carries the input power.

Comment: As an American EE, the term "lead" to mean a wire is not uncommon at all. It might be a bit less common in print than in spoken English, to avoid confusion with "lead", the metal that used to a component of solder.

Comment: Answer changed to reflect the input from the comment above.